# Find source and final destination using sql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, distinct, window-functions

I have a table source_flight_destination like this

| ID | Flight | source | destination |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Indigo | II | BB |
| 2 | Air Asia | AA | II |
| 3 | Indigo | BB | JJ |
| 4 | spice jet | SS | BB |
| 5 | Indigo | JJ | SS |
| 6 | Air Asia | II | KK |
| 7 | spice jet | BB | JJ |

The output should be flight, source and destination like this

| flight | source | destination |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Air Asia | AA | KK |
| Indigo | II | SS |
| Spicejet | SS | JJ |

I came up with a working solution:

```
with ranked as (
    select *,
    row_number() over (partition by flight order by id asc) as rn
    from source_destination_flight
),
minima as (
    select flight, min(rn) as minrn from ranked group by flight ),
maxima as (
    select flight, max(rn) as maxrn from ranked group by flight),
sourced as (
        select 
              r.flight, 
              r.source as source 
        from ranked r 
        join minima m1 on m1.flight=r.flight and m1.minrn=r.rn
),
destination as (
     select 
           r1.flight, 
           r1.destination as destination 
     from ranked r1 
     join maxima m2 
     on m2.flight=r1.flight and m2.maxrn=r1.rn
)
select
    s.flight, s.source, d.destination from sourced s join destination d on s.flight=d.flight
```

The idea was to:

- give a row_number() grouped by flight as partition,
- find minima and maxima of row_number for each partition,
- select source and destination by filtering out on basis of minima and maxima.

Yet this solution looks downright ugly and I am sure there is a much simpler solution out there.

Can anyone give me pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this sample data you can use window function `FIRST_VALUE()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Flight,
       FIRST_VALUE(source) OVER (PARTITION BY Flight ORDER BY ID) AS source,
       FIRST_VALUE(destination) OVER (PARTITION BY Flight ORDER BY ID DESC) AS destination
FROM source_destination_flight;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/fngWRJVd).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly what you are trying to do, taking the first row of a Flight for the Source and the last for the Destination, then this produces the list you said you wanted. I don't know how its performance will compare with forpas'. You'll just have to try it.

```
SELECT a.Flight, a.Source, c.Destination
FROM source_destination_flight a,
  (SELECT d.Flight, Min(d.id) AS Minid, Max(d.id) AS Maxid 
    FROM source_destination_flight d GROUP BY Flight) b,
  source_destination_flight c
WHERE a.id = b.Minid
AND c.id = b.Maxid;
```